# Read a udp stream in python using open-cv

Tags: javascript, python, opencv, udp, video-streaming

i have a udp stream coming from Web sockets in chunks from a remote video stream in the form

```
remoteCandidate: {candidateType: "host", ip: "3.XXX.XXX.XXX", port: XXXXX, priority: XXXXXXXXXX, protocol: "udp",…}
```

Instead of X, they are actual numbers, i have masked them for security purpose...

i want to read this stream in python using open cv to run machine learning models on it

here is my code so far, it throws the error
`Couldn't read video stream from file "udp://3.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXXX"`

```
import cv2

cascPath = 'haarcascade_frontalface_dataset.xml'  # dataset
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture('udp://3.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXXX')  

while (video_capture.isOpened()):
     # Capture frame-by-frame
    _, frame = video_capture.read()
    print(_)
    print(frame)
    cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
    
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything is done, release the capture
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Have you tried ffmpeg?
Try something like 
```cv2.VideoCapture("udp://3.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXXX", cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)```